# Android studio-java focus on listitem doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to reverse engieering a Dialer from a 4.4.4 android device.
I added a `onkeydown` listener ,so when the user press the '9' button,the listview in the **callLogActivity** should scroll to top.
Of course I'm editing the smali files,not the java itself,but I'll attach a java code of everything I tried,which didn't give the desired result

```
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == 16) {
        listview.requestFocus();
        listview.setSelection(0);
        listview.setSelectionAfterHeaderView();
        listview.setItemChecked(0, true);
        return true;
        return  super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
}
```

As you can see,I tried many similar methods, such as `setSelection()` and `setItemChecked()` and more....
Actually,The list indeed scrolls to top,but the focus(selected) still stay on the current ListItem..
It's not just a visual effect problem,the focus really stay on the current item(you can see it when you just hit the "ok" button).

**If you were wondering** what's the meaning of "pressing the ok or '9' button" ,it's the time to expose that device model, it's the xiaomi qin 1s,a feature phone with android OS on it.

Did i miss something?